# How do I get this 2D Array to rotate to the right 90 degrees?

Tags: java, arrays, rotation, 2d

So I have a 2D array, and it is supposed to rotate to the right 90 degrees, but instead it rotates to the left.  Really can't figure out why

public class CrackCode16 {

```
public static void main (String args[]){
    int [] [] oldarray = new int [3][3];

    int value = 1;

    for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++){
        for (int j =0; j<3; j++){
            oldarray[i][j] = value;
            value++;
        }
    }


    for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++){
        for (int j =0; j<3; j++){
            System.out.print(oldarray[i][j] + "\t");
        }
        System.out.println("");
    }


    oldarray = rotate(oldarray, 3);


    System.out.println("");
    for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++){
        for (int j =0; j<3; j++){
            System.out.print(oldarray[i][j] + "\t");
        }
        System.out.println("");
    }

}

public static int [][] rotate (int [][] passedIn, int n){

    int [][] newarray = new int [n][n];

    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++){
        for (int j =0; j<n; j++){
            newarray[i][j] = passedIn [j][n-1-i];
        }
    }   

    return newarray;
}
```

}

Output:

1   2   3
4   5   6
7   8   9

3   6   9
2   5   8
1   4   7

Comment: What is expected result?

Comment: Try `newarray[i][j] = passedIn[j][i]` in `rotate()` method.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
newArray[i][j] = passedIn [n-1-j][i];
```

instead of

```
newarray[i][j] = passedIn [j][n-1-i];
```

Additionally, when working with Java8, you might consider using a `Stream` to print your array:

```
Stream.of(oldarray).forEach(e -> System.out.println(Arrays.toString(e)));
```

Comment: That did it...thanks man..don't know why I didnt see this..I literally wrote out every element

Comment: @user3476554 You are very welcome (and welcome to SO as well ;) ). Your may mark an answer as "accepted" if it satisfied you.